# ASP.NET WebForms Placeholder for NVelocity View Engine

Tags: asp.net, webforms, placeholder, nvelocity

Is there any way to use placeholder similar to WebForms in NVelocity View Engine (.vm files)?

Today I've got a component containing everything for the `<head>`, but I wish to specify additional tags from each view page like it can easily be done in ASP.NET WebForms / MVC:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"></asp:Content>
```

If this is not possible directly trough NVelocity View Engine, do I have any other alternatives other than using a blank MasterPage and adding all markup in each view page?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, specify a variable. This will act like your content place holder:

```
$!header
```

Then in your page, you can specify content for that:

```
#capturefor(header)
     <b>html for my header</b>
#end
```

I hope you already found that answer! But just in case, and for anyone looking, there you have it.